# Serverless framework is not deploying an API Gateway on AWS from configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm trying to use the Serverless framework to create a Lambda which is invoked when a client connects to a websocket API Gateway. AWS CloudFormation is creating the Lambda functions that are defined but the websocket API Gateway isn't being created.

After attempting to write my own (which didn't work) I resorted to copy and pasting the examples I've found on Serverless docs into a freshly created serverless folder just to see if it would work - it didn't, and I can't find anyone else who seems to have had a similar problem.

---

So far I've tried the simple and extended methods documented here (which is what the example code is based on):
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/websocket/

And I've also tried to follow this blog, which also resulted in the Lambda creation but not an API Gateway.
https://serverless.com/blog/api-gateway-websockets-example/

Here's my serverless.yml file. It deploys as I would expect, apart from the API Gateway:

```
service: temp
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  region: eu-west-2

functions:
  default:
    handler: handler.connect
    events:
      - websocket: 
        route: $default
```

Here is the serverless deploy -v output:

```
$ serverless deploy -v
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Creating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack create progress...
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - temp-dev
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::S3::Bucket - ServerlessDeploymentBucket
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::S3::Bucket - ServerlessDeploymentBucket
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::S3::Bucket - ServerlessDeploymentBucket
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - temp-dev
Serverless: Stack create finished...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service .zip file to S3 (386 B)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
CloudFormation - UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - temp-dev
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Logs::LogGroup - DefaultLogGroup
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::IAM::Role - IamRoleLambdaExecution
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Logs::LogGroup - DefaultLogGroup
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::Logs::LogGroup - DefaultLogGroup
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::IAM::Role - IamRoleLambdaExecution
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::IAM::Role - IamRoleLambdaExecution
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Function - DefaultLambdaFunction
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Function - DefaultLambdaFunction
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::Lambda::Function - DefaultLambdaFunction
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Version - DefaultLambdaVersionY0DDREbM8apFqgW7p0WqFe2SjYB4Wt7O63fYPiljU
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Version - DefaultLambdaVersionY0DDREbM8apFqgW7p0WqFe2SjYB4Wt7O63fYPiljU
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::Lambda::Version - DefaultLambdaVersionY0DDREbM8apFqgW7p0WqFe2SjYB4Wt7O63fYPiljU
CloudFormation - UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - temp-dev
CloudFormation - UPDATE_COMPLETE - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - temp-dev
Serverless: Stack update finished...
Service Information
service: temp
stage: dev
region: eu-west-2
stack: temp-dev
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  None
functions:
  default: temp-dev-default
layers:
  None

Stack Outputs
DefaultLambdaFunctionQualifiedArn: arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:[redacted]:function:temp-dev-default:3
ServerlessDeploymentBucketName: temp-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-[redacted]
```

---

If anyone can shed some light on this as I may be completely missing something obvious, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Do you get any error when deploying ? Have you tried `serverless deploy --verbose` to see if you can get more hints ? What exactly is wrong with the deployment ? Nothing is created in API gateway ?

Comment: @Hugo I don't get any errors. It fails silently. I've just added the output of `serverless deploy -v` to the question.

Yes, nothing is created in API Gateway like you would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through literally everything related to Serverless I realised my Serverless version is not the most recent one (don't ask me how that happened, I ran `yarn add serverless` to get a project specific version of it yesterday)

Instead, the version was 1.35 and thus had no support for API Gateway websockets. Perhaps I had installed it globally at a previous point and neglected to remove it from my global npm packages...

The fact it was failing to recognise the tags silently did not help the debugging process and I might - when I get chance - contribute to the project by adding a validation run on the Serverless.yml files so unsupported options are flagged in the console.

As it was, running `npm install -g serverless@latest` fixed the problem and now the API Gateway gets deployed correctly.

Thank you Alex and Hugo for responding!

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same issue and for me the solution was to indent `route` properly like this:

```
functions:
  default:
    handler: handler.connect
    events:
      - websocket: 
          route: $default
```

So basically change:

```
- websocket: 
  route: $default
```

to:

```
- websocket: 
    route: $default
```

Comment: Oh wow, I had this exact same issue.  There was no warning output from severless deploy and the difference is quite subtle as the dash before the parent makes things look indented at a glance